# Event on plugins C#

Tags: c#, plugins, event-handling

I have plugin-based console application.
I want to send an event for plugins when a key is pressed on the console so that the plugins do the necessary work
What code should I add to PluginManager.cs?

this is plugin manager source:

```
public static List<IPlugin> Plugins { get; set; }

public void LoadPlugins(string folderpath) {
    Plugins = new List<IPlugin>();

    if (Directory.Exists(folderpath))
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderpath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (file.EndsWith(".dll"))
            {
                Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath(file));
            }
        }
    }

    Type interfaceType = typeof(IPlugin);
    Type[] types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass)
        .ToArray();
    foreach (Type type in types)
        Plugins.Add((IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
}

public static void Write(string parameters) {
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now, parameters);
}
```

IPlugin:

```
public interface IPlugin {
    string Command { get; }
    string Discription { get; }
    void Execute(string parameters);
    void OnLoad();
    void OnDown();
}
```

Plugin example:

```
public class Say : IPlugin {
    public void Execute(string parameters) { PluginManager.Write(parameters); }
    public void OnLoad() { PluginManager.Write("Enabling Say"); }
    public void OnDown() { PluginManager.Write("Disabling Say"); }
    public string Command  { get { return "Say"; } }
    public string Discription { get { return "Write that you want"; } }
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a method in `IPlugin` that should be called when a key is pressed? Then you can just iteratate over `Plugins` and call this method on all the plugins

Comment: I do not want plugins that do not need OnKeyPress to have that method, still need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an interface

```
interface IConsumeKeyboardEvents
{
  void OnKeyPress(ConsoleKey key);
}
```

and implement it only by those plugins that need to get the key event:

```
public class Say : IPlugin, IConsumeKeyboardEvents
{
    public void OnKeyPress(ConsoleKey key) 
    { }
}
```

Your plugin manager can then call all the plugins with this interface. For C# version 8.0 or later:

```
public void OnKeyPress(ConsoleKey key) 
{
    foreach (var plugin in Plugins)
    {
        if (plugin is IConsumeKeyboardEvents keyboardPlugin)
        {
            keyboardPlugin.OnKeyPress(key);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are on C# before version 8.0 (so pattern matching is  not supported), this has to be changed to:

```
public void OnKeyPress(ConsoleKey key) 
{
    foreach (var plugin in Plugins)
    {
        var keyboardPlugin = plugin as IConsumeKeyboardEvents;
        if (keyboardPlugin != null)
        {
            keyboardPlugin.OnKeyPress(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `keyboardPlugin` . i got this errors: [Image](https://postimg.cc/gallery/SqK5cM0)

Comment: Edited the answer to cover also older C# versions

Comment: How? can i get More details please

Comment: Did you see my edited answer? The last snippet should work for you.